# How to eliminate Focus Assist notification?

Tags: windows-10, notification-area, focus-assist

Focus Assist is my default. Always.

I'm trying to reduce the notifications in the Action Center to the minimum possible.

How can I remove this notification for good:

[image]

To clarify, I want Focus Assist to be always on. I don't need THIS notification to tell me that.

I'm good with the little [image] icon to tell me that. Hence I want the notification saying "Your notifications will remain quite here..." removed, while Focus Assist is on.

Comment: Did you click "turn off now"?

Comment: It is not super clear what you're asking. Are you saying you wish Focus Assist to run (remain active) but you don't want to see the Notification Toast for Focus Assist? Please edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: @music2myear, yes, that's what I'd want, I've updated my question.

Comment: Have you tried just toggling off Focus Assist on the Notifications page in settings?

Comment: I don't want to turn off focus assist. I want it to be on. I just want to avoid this notification coming up over and over.